# Question on Locke and Hobbes's views on private property

Tags: locke, hobbes

I've read chapters 1-9 of Locke's Second Treatise of Government as well as chapters i, x, xiii-xviii, and xxi of Hobbes's Leviathan.

While Locke spends the entire fifth chapter discussing private property, Hobbes's view is more nuanced.

I want to know what their main difference is on the nature of private property and how that necessarily entails that they would have different views on the individual and society.

Comment: Sounds like a homework question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both Hobbes and Locke were responding to a particular problematic of the 17th century. At that time, commoners were beginning to develop substantial wealth, through foreign adventures, commercial activities, and the pre-industrial guild system (let's call these commoners the 'bourgeoisie', using Marx's term). The nobility and aristocracy still garnered most of their wealth through taxes and expropriation, and that was breeding resentment among the bourgeoisie who (naturally) wanted to retain the wealth they earned. That made the question of where 'ownership' comes from philosophically pressing.

Hobbes asserted that *ownership* was merely an expression of power. In uncivilized conditions (the State of Nature) ownership (he thought) is determined by brute force and incessant conflict, so civilized conditions require that power be turned back to suppress these brute tendencies. For Hobbes, then, ownership was conveyed by legal or factual authority, backed up by the physical force available to the state. In a sense, Hobbes was following the traditional feudal model: the monarch owns everything in his realm, but grants land and authority to the aristocracy, who in turn grant land to tenant farmers, all in exchange for tithes and taxes that flow back up the chain. But even in non-monarchical ('liberal') forms of government, Hobbes felt that the state should be the ultimate source of ownership. People who come together to create a state must create a state capable of suppressing their own brute natures, and which will establish who owns what authoritatively through law and policy.

Most of the prominent Liberal philosophers of that era had read Hobbes, and were unsurprisingly appalled at the notion that men must create oppressive regimes to control what they cannot control in themselves. So they looked for different ways of conceptualizing the issue. Locke settle on the idea that ownership was based not in *power* but in *labor*. In brief, Locke assumed that (in the State of Nature) a person *for certain* owns a piece of food when he has eaten that food and digested it into his system. But in order to eat it he must prepare it, and in order to prepare it he must gather the ingredients from the abundance of nature. So to Locke's mind, once someone has begun investing labor in a thing — the gathering and preparing stage — that thing is his as surely as if he had already digested it. Ownership is a 'property' of human existence, just as flesh and bones are, and taking a man's property is tantamount to taking his arm or leg. While power may come into play in human interactions — and notably, in Locke's State of Nature man is largely solitary and self-sufficient — power is not the source of ownership, but either an impediment to it or an extra labor that must be expended to defend that innate, labor-given right to own.

I think the differences in Hobbes' and Locke's political views follow naturally from this distinction between ownership-from-power and ownership-from-labor, not to mention the 'social contract' theory promoted by Rousseau or the 'market' theory of Adam Smith. I'm not sure what more I can say on that without getting into needless digressions, so I'll halt here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think their different views on the nature of private property are what motivates their different views on the individual and society. I think they get their different views on the individual and society, *and* their different views on the nature of private property, from their different "state of nature" myths (i.e. myths about the origins of society).

But (teach a man to fish) if you have the texts in front of you and you're reading them, and want to know the main difference between Hobbes' and Locke's views of private property, look at Hobbes' definition of private property, break it down into a list of essential features, do the same for Locke's definition of private property, and then identify the points that contradict each other across the two lists.